Cannot print bibliography with BibLaTeX in standalone document class
I use the standalone package and document class frequently in my documents to keep figures and main document matter separate (and to be able to easily reuse the figures later).
I try to keep the standalone files self-contained so that I can render them into a PDF without touching the main document they are included in.
To this end, I often use \providecommand, \providecolor, etc. to provide fallback behaviour for certain macros used in the figures.
Now I want to do the same with bibliography items.
I have a standalone document with some citations.
I want to provide the references for these citations within the standalone document as a fallback in case I am compiling as a real standalone document.
Here is an MWE:
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@misc{foo,
  title = {Foo, Bar, Baz: The Real Meaning of Metasyntactic Variables},
  author = {Smith, John and Doe, Jane},
  year = 2024
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

John and Jane explain the meaning behind famous metasyntactic variables in great detail~\cite{foo}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}

Note that in reality, I want to wrap parts of the document like \printbibliography in a \ifstandalone [...] \fi conditional, but I wanted to keep it as simple as possible here.
Unfortunately, the code above does not compile for me due to:
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

This only happens when the document class is standalone.
When using article, it compiles just fine.

You could use the varwidth option:
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@misc{foo,
  title = {Foo, Bar, Baz: The Real Meaning of Metasyntactic Variables},
  author = {Smith, John and Doe, Jane},
  year = 2024
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

John and Jane explain the meaning behind famous metasyntactic variables in great detail~\cite{foo}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}



Wow, that is such a simple solution. Thank you. I am trying to learn more about (La)TeX; I would appreciate it if you or anybody could give me a few pointers on why this works (or, more importantly, why compilation fails without varwidth). Nonetheless, the issue is solved.

@bp99 By default, the standalone class does have a text width, which causes problems with a lot of commonly used elements, like equations. The varwidth option will give the document a width. (I'm not sure what the advantage of using the standalone class for references is, though...)
